# How to use a React component as options of Form.Select in React-Bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm implementing a **Form.Select** that should have another react component as its options.

Here, the name of the **Form.Select** is "Collection" and its options should be a card component (with an image) called "CollectionCard".

This is the expected implementation.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yWZ3.png
(Refer this image)

And, here is my current code.

```
<Form.Group controlId="form.collection">
    <Form.Label className="fw-bold">Collection</Form.Label>
    <Form.Select className="mb-5" aria-label="Collection">
        <option value="1">
            <CollectionCard />
        </option>
        <option value="2">
            <CollectionCard />
        </option>
    </Form.Select>
</Form.Group>
```

But this is how it actually shows in the UI with the above code.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eI8hv.png
(Refer this image)

The "CollectionCard" component is not getting rendered inside the **Form.Select** and it shows as **[object Object]**.

**Updated**
I tried adding {} for the "CollectionCard" as well,

```
<option value="2">
   {<CollectionCard />}
</option>
```

Still not working.

**Updated**
Adding CollectionCard component code below.

```
import React from 'react';

import './CollectionCard.scss';

import {Card} from 'react-bootstrap';

export const CollectionCard: React.FC = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="collection-card">
            <Card className="d-flex flex-row border-0 bg-transparent">
                <Card.Img className="card-img-xs" src={require('../../../../assets/nft-sample.png')} alt="img" />
                <Card.Body className="p-0 ms-3 align-self-center">
                    Lorep Ipsum
                </Card.Body>
            </Card>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Please help me to get this resolved.
Thanks!

Comment: Please show CollectionCard componenet return code

Comment: @MUsama Updated the question with that.

Comment: it's not a trivial task, as Form.Select expects option to be a child. Also, you can't put nodes inside of option, only inner text.

Comment: @IgorGonak If so, is there a workaround to implement this kind of a select? Like, with an (image + text) as options?

Comment: You can use [react-bootstrap-select](https://github.com/tjwebb/react-bootstrap-select) or [react-select](https://react-select.com/) they have image options

Answer (score -1):

just set your component inside of bracket

```
<Form.Group controlId="form.collection">
<Form.Label className="fw-bold">Collection</Form.Label>
<Form.Select className="mb-5" aria-label="Collection">
    <option value="1">
        {<CollectionCard />}
    </option>
    <option value="2">
        {<CollectionCard />}
    </option>
</Form.Select>
</Form.Group>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I tried with that also. It's not working.